# Create Custom product type with Associated products tab

Tags: magento-1.9, module, grouped-products, custom-product-type

I want to create a new Custom product type similar to the Grouped Product esp. which have associated products tab on product page in backend.  I have tried with following tags in my module config.xml file.

```
  <catalog>
        <product>
            <type>
                <bookable translate="label" module="bookable">
                    <label>Bookable Product</label>
                    <model>bookable/product_type_packet</model>
                    <is_qty>1</is_qty>
                    <composite>0</composite>               
                     <allowed_selection_types>
                          <simple/>
                          <grouped/>
                     </allowed_selection_types>
                </bookable>
            </type>
        </product>
    </catalog>
```

Please advise me how I can achieve this job.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

https://community.magento.com/t5/Building-Extensions/Custom-Product-Type-which-extends-Grouped-Product-Type/td-p/16251

The Associated Products tab is added via XML with a handle that is specific to that product type. You will need to add a similar update for your product type in your own admin layout xml file

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/catalog.xml

```
<adminhtml_catalog_product_grouped>
    <reference name="product_tabs">
        <action method="addTab"><name>super</name><block>adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_super_group</block></action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_catalog_product_grouped>
```

If you're trying to copy grouped pretty much exactly using the grouped handle as an update like below may work best:

```
<adminhtml_catalog_product_newtypeidhere>
    <update handle="adminhtml_catalog_product_grouped"/>
</adminhtml_catalog_product_newtypeidhere>
```

Credit to James Anelay