# custom product type based on grouped product with associated tab

Tags: module, layout, magento-1, custom, product-type

I want to **create a custom product type similar to grouped product** and I got help from [here](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2015/06/17/create-custom-product-types/) so I created a new module

[image]

I already read [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60334/create-custom-product-type-with-associated-products-tab) however could not solve my problem.:
here is what I did in config.xml:

```
    <catalog>
        <product>
            <type>
                <excellence translate="label" module="excellence_test">
                    <label>Custom Product</label>
                   <model>excellence_test/basket_product</model>
                    <price_model>catalog/product_type_grouped_price</price_model>
                    <composite>1</composite>
                    <allow_product_types>
                        <simple/>
                        <grouped/>
                    </allow_product_types>
                    <index_priority>50</index_priority>
                    <price_indexer>catalog/product_indexer_price_grouped</price_indexer>
                </excellence>
            </type>
        </product>
    </catalog>
```

here is my Model:

```
class Excellence_Test_Model_Basket_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Abstract
{
    public function isComposite($product = null)
    {
        return true;
    }
   public function setTypeId($typeId)
    {

        return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_GROUPED;
    }
}
```

regarding to the link I should determine to add associated products tab, how ever it does not read the xml file at all!, I don't even have any erros:

I have layout update in my config.xml:

```
 <adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <excellence_test>
                <file>excellence/catalog.xml</file>
            </excellence_test>
        </updates>
    </layout>
 </adminhtml>
```

This still is not showing me the associated product tab.
here is the path file to my layout file:

`app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\excellence\catalog.xml`

inside I wrote this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
<adminhtml_catalog_product_excellence>
    <reference name="product_tabs">
        <action method="addTab">
            <name>super</name>
            <block>adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_super_group</block>
        </action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_catalog_product_excellence>
</layout>
```

even if I write  it does not throw any errors so I guess my file even is not being read.

here is config.xml per Raphael request:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Excellence_Test>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Excellence_Test>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <catalog>
            <product>
                <type>
                    <excellence translate="label" module="excellence_test">
                        <label>Custom Product</label>
                       <model>excellence_test/basket_product</model>
                        <price_model>catalog/product_type_grouped_price</price_model>
                        <composite>1</composite>
                        <allow_product_types>
                            <simple/>
                            <grouped/>
                        </allow_product_types>
                        <index_priority>50</index_priority>
                        <price_indexer>catalog/product_indexer_price_grouped</price_indexer>
                    </excellence>
                </type>
            </product>
        </catalog>

        <resources>
            <excellence_test_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Excellence_Test</module>
                    <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </excellence_test_setup>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <excellence_test>
                <class>Excellence_Test_Block</class>
            </excellence_test>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <excellence_test>
                <class>Excellence_Test_Helper</class>
            </excellence_test>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <excellence_test>
                <class>Excellence_Test_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>excellence_test_resource</resourceModel>
            </excellence_test>
            <excellence_test_resource>
                <class>Excellence_Test_Model_Resource</class>
            </excellence_test_resource>
        </models>

    </global>

     <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <excellence_test>
                    <file>excellence/catalog.xml</file>
                </excellence_test>
            </updates>
        </layout>
     </adminhtml>

</config>
```

please help me.code is [available](https://github.com/neginparsa/magentodev)

Comment: Could you post your full `config.xml` file please

Comment: done, I included the full config.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it, The problem was, I should also define the phtml file, I have done the following in catalog.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
<adminhtml_catalog_product_excellence>
    <reference name="product_tabs">
        <action method="addTab">
            <name>super</name>
            <block>adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_super_group</block>
        </action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_catalog_product_excellence>
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_excellence>
        <reference name="product.composite.fieldset">
            <block type="adminhtml/catalog_product_composite_fieldset_grouped" name="product.composite.fieldset.grouped" before="product.composite.fieldset.options" template="catalog/product/composite/fieldset/grouped.phtml"/>
            <remove name="product.composite.fieldset.qty"/>
        </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_excellence>
</layout>
```

Then I saw that function getAssociatedProducts cannot be called so I extended different class for my model as the following:

```
class Excellence_Test_Model_Basket_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Grouped 
{

}
```

so instead of extending the Abstract, I extend the grouped, and now I can customize this type of product based on my requirements.I also pushed the code to [github](https://github.com/neginparsa/magentodev) so it is available for whoever wanted to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you've been mislead by the adminhtml XML layout.

Your layout handle `adminhtml_catalog_product_excellence` means that the code will only be called when accessing /admin/catalog/product/excellence route. However, in your case you want to add that tab when you're accessing a product edit page.

I first wanted to suggest you to use this code instead:

```
<adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
    <reference name="product_tabs">
        <action method="addTab">
            <name>super</name>
            <block>adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_super_group</block>
        </action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
```

But I'm afraid it will add the tab to every edit page even if your new product type is not used.

I suggest you try this instead:

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_excellence>
    <reference name="product_tabs">
        <action method="addTab">
            <name>super</name>
            <block>adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_super_group</block>
        </action>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_excellence>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried your code and still I see no results, as I mentioned something is wrong in my layout since I think excellence/catalog.xml  is not even read, I can write whatever and no errors will show up.

Comment: you gave me the idea of product_type_excellence and I went through core and saw what I can do about it so +1, thank you!

Comment: @Nickool glad you fixed it